# Django 1.6/Python 2.7 - Populate editable form from model in view/template

Tags: python, django

I am having difficulty creating a form that pre-populates with editable data from a series of models. The goal is to essentially create a visual representation of editable key value pairs to be processed later into json. The admin section would then be used to add new keys and default values for the users to edit, or to delete keys outright.

Any insight on how to do this would be very helpful, I can handle the json part myself but I am still getting started with Django and haven't been able to produce the desired results from any of the various examples I've located (perhaps I just don't know what to search for).

My application's models.py file looks like the following:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Path(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    default = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.path

class Feature(models.Model):
    killswitch = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    default = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.killswitch

class Other(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    default = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category
```

Any help, tips, or advice is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your form and view code too?

Comment: I haven't gotten far enough along with any of that to provide viable code yet unfortunately. Its really up in the air at time of writing.

Comment: Sorry to be vague, I'm really not too sure about how to move forward with this and am reading feverishly trying to find an answer.

Comment: This book http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html is a comprehensive introduction...

Comment: One possible workaround is: Create another model named Stub or something. In all above models, create a ForeignKey relation, in admin.py, StubAdmin with inlines = [PathInline, FeatureInline]. Then in Stub admin page, you can edit them in one page